# Unable to create or query custom object records from guest user

Tags: community, permissions

I have a self-registration page for my community. I am able to create users and contacts but when it fires the trigger it

```
lmscons.SFDCAccessControlException: Access Violation Exception
```

I have added Read write create delete and view all permission in Public Access setting for the sites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting error because of Guest user limitations, your trigger is updating standard object which is not allowed for a Guest User.

Following are the limitation for guest users.

**A guest user cannot edit a standard object, but they can read/create one.**

**If any custom object has a master detail relationship to a standard object that the user can't see, the can't see the child object either.**

No reporting or dashboarding.

The guest user can own records, but can't be part of sharing rules.

The guest user doesn't have any error details on their error page. If you have an apex runtime exception, you'll get an auth error instead of the actual error in the UI.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76170/discussion-on-answer-by-prabhat-kumar-unable-to-create-or-query-custom-object-re).